# How to listen for systemDidWake events on macOS?

Tags: swift, macos, events, nsnotificationcenter, macos-sonoma

How do I listen for an event for when the Mac wakes up from sleep?

I have code to listen for screen lock and unlock events, BUT when the system wakes from deep sleep<sup>1</sup> the unlock event doesn't fire. Therefore I want to also listen for the `systemDidWake` or similar event.

The code I have now for listening for lock/unlock events look like this:

```swift
#!/usr/bin/env swift

import Foundation

class ScreenLockObserver {
    init() {
        let dnc = DistributedNotificationCenter.default()

        // listen for screen lock
        let _ = dnc.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name("com.apple.screenIsLocked"), object: nil, queue: .main) { _ in
            NSLog("Screen Locked")
        }

        // listen for screen unlock
        let _ = dnc.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name("com.apple.screenIsUnlocked"), object: nil, queue: .main) { _ in
            NSLog("Screen Unlocked")
        }

        RunLoop.main.run()
    }
}

let _ = ScreenLockObserver()
```

I'm testing this on a M3 MacBook running macOS Sonoma 14.1.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> When the Mac has been closed for 8-12+ hours, preferably without power.</sup>

Comment: Your code works as expected on my M2 MacBook Air (Sonoma 14.3).

Comment: Leave the scrip running when you turn off the mac for the night(not sure how long you have to wait) and when you turn it on again the unlock event doesn't fire  i.e. there are a deeper sleep that happens (my working theory at least)

Comment: Last night I closed the lid of my MBA at about 10pm, and opened it this morning at about 6:30am. Both events were logged by the program.

Comment: I woke up my M3 now(08:14) from when I turned it of yesterday at 20:08, and the unlock event didn't fire Did you leave yours connected to power? I'm not 100% sure about the conditions for the event not firing, but it happens regularly enough that I can't just ignore it.

Comment: Sorry but I cannot reproduce the problem. I had the MBA now closed for > 10 hours, without power supply, and still got the unlock event. Unfortunately I have no idea what the problem could be.

Comment: Have you tried `NSWorkSpace`s `.didWakeNotification`?

Comment: @Willeke No but I would really appreciate an example. The examples I have found seems to be for older versions of swift, the examples doesn't even compile

Comment: it's just a notification like the notifications in your question. Use `NSWorkspace.notificationCenter` instead of `DistributedNotificationCenter.default()`.

Comment: @Willeke Got errors when trying that, see [gist](https://gist.github.com/karl-gustav/ac76fe7751e01b5384abfdd7a3b7e951)

Comment: It is `NSWorkspace.shared.notificationCenter`

Comment: `NSWorkspace` is in framework AppKit. And yes, it's `NSWorkspace.shared.notificationCenter`, sorry for that.

Comment: @Willeke Now it seems like it can't find `NSWorkspace.didWakeNotification`. I have updated the [gist](https://gist.github.com/karl-gustav/ac76fe7751e01b5384abfdd7a3b7e951) with the full error message.

Comment: @Pylinux: Similar errors were reported here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/710274. As a workaround you can compile the program first with `switfc` and then run the compiled binary.